# Movie where a protagonist wears a helmet that contains lost or ancient knowledge

Tags: story-identification, movie

There is an old movie (70s or early 80s) where the protagonist in the later part of the film wears a helmet that restores (his?) memory, they come to him in fast forward imagery.

From what I recall the helmet/surroundings were Roman-like perhaps.

Comment: Hi a few more details would be appreciated. Take the tour and learn how to add a few more details to your question... https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I can see two possibilities here one could be the (hilariously) bad Flash Gordon film which has a scene with a character having his memories erased...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtKFB0pERx4 see if this fits or it could be the film Brainstorm which features memories recorded through a helmet... not at all sure if either of these adequately fits what you describe though...You can watch Brainstorm on youtube here...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOGAEAJ4xJE

Comment: I don't know that this is specifically sci-fi or fantasy. Can you elaborate on how it is?

Comment: @Möoz how could it not be? Do you know of any non-SF technology that can restore memories by means of a helmet?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's not evident that it's the helmet that facilitates the memory gain, or merely triggers a hallucinogenic episode.

Comment: @Mooz. A helmet that does anything other than adorn and protect the head in ancient Roman times? Really?